# Using CameraRoll component local images are not displaying

Tags: ios, react-native

while accesing local images using CameraRollView component this error is observed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Camera roll view has been removed from iOS 8 onwards. The closest thing that resembles it is the collection view.

Comment: What is collection view and how to i get the images in ios 8 also

Comment: Collection view is a type of reusable view just like table view.